# google sheets script compare values of one row with 2 different sheets rows and if it doesn't match copy to a third sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a google sheet called Voters with 2 tabs, the first is Votazione the other is BackUpVotazione. There are some drop down menues in cells A2, B3-B12 with data collected from column A of another sheet called MainExcel.
If a value in A2 is selected from the drop down menu, the corrispective value stored in sheet MainExcel in rows B to E are copied in rows C to F of the Votazione sheet, than that row is deleted from MainExcel.
If a value in B3-B12 is selected from the drop down menu, the corrispective value stored in sheet MainExcel in rows B to E are copied in rows C to F of the Votazione sheet, than that row is deleted from MainExcel.
In row B13 of the Votazione sheet, if 0 is typed than values stored in A2, C2-F2 and eventually values in B3-F12 are copied to a third sheet called BackUpVotazioni (with I, sorry for similar sheet name) in the same position they are stored in the Votazione sheet.
In row B13 of the Votazione sheet, if 1 is typed than values stored in A2, C2-F2 and eventually values in B3-F12 are copied to a third sheet called BackUpVotazoni in cells A to E.

Sorry for my bad english, probably and image would be helpful. Here it is:

[Sample of working sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NdXA.png)

I need a way to avoid double values or missing ones.

By now the user can only modify cells A2 and B3-B13, but if he choose a value for example in cell A2 and than choose another one in same cell the previous value choosen was deleted and no more available.
There will be many users, working on MainExcel and BackUpVotazione
I was thinking to copy the selected values in another sheet, than if the values exists in sheets BackUpVotazioni or in MainExcel just delete them. If the values doesn't exist in BackUpVotazioni or MainExcel than copy it to MainExcel (append the row).

Thanks in advance for your time.

This is what I've achieved right now:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let sheet = range.getSheet();
  let value = e.value;
  let row = range.getRow()
  

  let wantInfo = (
    sheet.getSheetName() == "Votazione" &&
    row != 1 &&
    (
      range.getColumn() == 1 ||
      range.getColumn() == 2
    )
  )

  let done = (value === "0")
  let undo = (value === "1")

  if (wantInfo & !done & !undo) {
    let s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID")
    let s1sheet = s1.getSheetByName("Votanti")
    let s2sheet = s1.getSheetByName("Selezionati")
    let s1values = s1range.getDataRange().getValues()
    let output = [];
    let rowToDelete;

    newS1values = s1values.filter((row, index) => {
      if (row[0] == value || row[1] == value){
        rowToDelete = index +1
        s2sheet.appendRow(row)   
        row.shift() 
        output.push(row)             
        return false
      } else return true 
    })

    let outputRange = sheet.getRange(row,3,1,4);
    outputRange.setValues(output)
    s1sheet.deleteRow(rowToDelete)
    
  } else if (undo) {
        let s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID")
        let s1sheet = s1.getSheetByName("Votanti")
        
        let s2range = sheet.getDataRange();
        let s2values = s2range.getValues();

         s1sheet.appendRow([s2values[1][0],s2values[1][2],s2values[1][3],s2values[1][4],s2values[1][5]])
      
         for (var i = 2; i < 12; i++) {
          s1sheet.appendRow([s2values[i][1],s2values[i][2],s2values[i][3],s2values[i][4],s2values[i][5]])}
  
        sheet.getRange("A2:F12").clearContent();
        sheet.getRange("A13:E13").clearContent();
        
  } else if (done) {
    let s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID")
    let s3sheet = s3.getSheetByName("RisultatoFinale")
    
    let s2range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let s2values = s2range.getValues();
    let headers = s2values.shift();
    
    s2values.pop();

    s2values.forEach(row => s3sheet.appendRow(row))

    sheet.getRange("A2:F12").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("A13:E13").clearContent();
    
    let headerRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers.length)
    headerRange.setValues([headers])
  }
}
function init(){}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that simple triggers must compltere within 30 seconds

Comment: Right now it takes 1/2 seconds for each value retrieve and 2/3 seconds when user types 0 or 1, in total it takes 20 to 25 seconds... I just need to get sure that there aren't deleted values and there are no double ones.

Comment: Sounds like you are awfully close to the limit and with varying server load you could easily  begin to fail on timeout.  You should begin to take better advantage of the info in the event object to  reduce the number of unnecessary function calls

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I tried to get it a bit more performing but without success xD- any help would be appreciated. However I opted to make the last modify by adding some formulas inside one of sheets.

Comment: e.range.getRow() is the same as e.range.rowStart except that there is no function call invlolved